# "or" condition doesn't work JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a condition which should predict run the function. but it wouldn't work.

```
if ((event.keyCode !== 40) || (event.keyCode !== 38)) {
        self.inputVal = input.value;
        var result = pokemonNames.filter(function(pokemon) {
          return pokemon.includes(self.inputVal.toLowerCase());
        });
        if (result.length > 5) {
          result = result.filter(function(pokemon, index) {
            return index < 5;
          });
        }
```

when I use just `event.keyCode !== 40` it works fine, but when I use `(event.keyCode !== 40) || (event.keyCode !== 38)` it would work.

Comment: It's your logic that's broken, it will always be different from one of the two codes. Your condition simplifies to `true`. You either want `(k != x) && (k != y)` or `(k == x) || (k ==y)`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Use && instead of ||

Comment: That condition "not 40 or not 38" will match any value.

Comment: I don't want to run that function if event.keyCode = 40 or 38

Comment: @VasylKozhushko please, take a minute to work it out by yourself. If that doesn't become natural to you, you'll have a hard time in the future.

Comment: Sorry @Aaron I should have let them try and figure it out a bit first

Comment: @JasonH no need to apologize to me ;) Anyway if you hadn't I'm sure someone else would have

Comment: @Aaron I am new in JS, and I understand that it is kind of simple question, but where I spouse to ask questions like this? and for what kind of questions Stackoverflow  is?

Comment: I'm not criticizing the fact that you asked, I'm just trying to give you an advice. You want to craft a condition that will be true when and only when a variable isn't one of two values. You probably know boolean operators `||` and `&&` as well as comparison operators `===` and `!==`, so you have all the knowledge need to do it, it's just that you're not familiar enough with them to directly know how to solve your problem. Well my point is that you will become familiar enough with them much faster if you take a minute to solve the problem by yourself rather than taking the answer from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the if block if the event.keyCode is NOT 40 or 38 you want this

```
((event.keyCode !== 40) && (event.keyCode !== 38))
```

If you want to execute the code if event.keyCode is 40 or 38

```
((event.keyCode == 40) || (event.keyCode == 38))
```

Comment: OK if you are going to downvote my answer, at least tell me why

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron pointed out in the comments, it will always resolve as `true`. If the number is 40, the second condition will be true (since it's not 38), and vice versa. Use `&&` instead and it will work.